# Right way to write down or use an operator?

Tags: notation, operator-theory

Let $f:X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I want to simplify an operator to denote the following functional transformation:
$$f(x,y) - \int_{Y}f(x,y)g(y)\,dy, $$
where $g$ is the pdf of $Y$. So I define operator $T$
$$T(f)(x,y) = f(x,y) - \int_{Y}f(x,y)g(y)\,dy.  $$

For function $f$, I do not think there is a problem with how I use the operator notation, but I want to use the same notation to simplify
$$\frac{f(x,y)}{f(c,y)} - \int_{Y}\frac{f(x,y)}{f(c,y)}g(y)\,dy, $$
where $c$ is some fixed constant. I heard that it is mathematically incorrect to use $$T\left(\frac{f(x,y)}{f(c,y)}\right).$$

Could there be any better way to use the operator $T$ for ${f(x,y)}/{f(c,y)}$?

Comment: I take $c$ is a given element of $X$. I'd go with "Let $h(x,y)=\dfrac{f(x,y)}{f(c,y)}$, for all $(x,y)$ in $X\times Y$" and then use $T(h)$.

Comment: @GitGud I agree. But I will need to change that constant $c$ time to time. In this case, it would be inefficient to define functions every time I change $c$.

Comment: Then use the symbol $h_c$ instead.